# Does an Expression in RPN Give us a Linear Way of Writing What Happens in a Circuit?

Tags: circuits

I mean, say we want to show how we can implement an OR gate in terms of a NAND gate. If we write in Polish notation, then we've suggested that the circuit takes the gates before the inputs. If we write it in infix notation, we've suggested a mix. But if we write ppDqqDD, then we've suggested that we have the input 'p', then 'p' again, then those pass through NAND in the circuit, 'q', then 'q' input again, then they pass through NAND, and finally the result of what the previous NANDs found passes through the final NAND.

So doesn't an expression in Reverse Polish Notation tell us exactly how a circuit behaves?  Or does it only describe the behavior of some circuits?  Which types of circuits, if any, does RPN describe in this way?

Comment: No, even with a "duplicate" operation, you can only represent trees, but not general acyclic graphs: [Is “duplicate” in RPN enough for replacing variable binding in term expressions?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/32151/is-duplicate-in-rpn-enough-for-replacing-variable-binding-in-term-expressions)

Comment: Because one needs variables anyway, one just omitts the stack. This notion is called straight line program, and it is equivalent to arithmetic circuits: [What is the relation between arithmetic circuits and straight line programs?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/35890/what-is-the-relation-between-arithmetic-circuits-and-straight-line-programs)

Comment: @ThomasKlimpel Make an answer?